# $P(x)$ converges iff $Q(x)$ converges. Does this imply that both have the same radius of convergence? where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are power series

Tags: power-series

Let $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ be two power series and $P(x)$ converges iff $Q(x)$ converges. Does this imply that both have the same radius of convergence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call $R$ the radius of convergence for $P$, and $R^\prime$ the one for $Q$. For $|x|<R$, $P(x)$ converges, so by assumption $Q(x)$ also converges and this implies $|x|\leqslant R^\prime$. But $|x|$ can be chosen as close of $R$ as we want, so $R \leqslant R^\prime$. Doing the same thing for $Q$ instead of $P$, you get $R^\prime \leqslant R$. Finally, $R=R^\prime$

Comment: what guarantees that $R\leq R'$ by choosing $|x|$ close to $R$ ?

Comment: Take $x_n$ such that $|x_n| <R$ and $|x_n| \to R$. Then for all $n$, $|x_n| \leqslant R^\prime$, and taking the limit gives $R \leqslant R^\prime$

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Indeed, you can define the radius of convergence of a power series $\sum a_n z^n$ as the supremum of the $r \in \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $\sum a_n r^n$ converges.

Comment: Will you please elaborate?